# How can make the trigger_word as argument to python?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, vimscript-python, snippets

The syntax of UltiSnips's snippet is as below:

```
snippet trigger_word [ "description" [ options ] ]
```

The upper method can convert all characters in the string into upper case:

```
"string".upper()
'STRING'
```

I want to write a small snippets to convert the trigger_word into it's upper case in html file.Add the below lines in `vim-snippets/UltiSnips\html.snippets`.

```
snippet string
`!p snip.rv="string".upper()`
endsnippet
```

`string` can expand into `STRING` when to edit html file,how can make any other string be expanded into it's uppercase status?For example,`otherstring` expanded into `OTHERSTRING`?If i get the way to get trigger_word as a variable ,then it's simple to convert in calling python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question it seems that a generic trigger is preferred. If so, a *regex snippet* would be useful here. The following changes `{somestring}.upper` to `{SOMESTRING}`:

```
snippet "(\w+)\.upper" "make upper" r
`!p snip.rv=match.group(1).upper()`
endsnippet
```

The `r` flag makes it a regex snippet, whose regex trigger is enclosed in quotes (`"(\w+)\.upper"`). (Note that python regex is used, and not vim regex.) The main string to be accessed is in `(\w+)`, which is the first captured group as part of the regex (`match.group(1)`). Finally, this is returned in its uppercase form.